# Aligning key colon value data in css without using HTML table?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following data that I want to show.
Ideally I want the `keys` and `values` left aligned, separated with `colons` in the middle.

I want the result to be like the following:

```
key1  : value1
key2  : value2
keyAbc: Value Abc
key_N : value N
```

And **not** like the following:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
keyAbc: Value Abc
key_N: value N
```

How to do this in CSS or SCSS, and not using HTML table?

Comment: Can you share your html structure? You can use `display: table` or `display: flex` even without using the html for table.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Use `display: table` for the container and `display: table-row` for each line and `display: table-cell` for each `${key}` and for each `: ${value}`. Basically immitating a `<table>` ([mdn - css - display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grid, making the columns take on the max width of content.

This snippet adds the colons in a pseudo element as they seem to be just a visual clue rather than part of the data.

Of course you will want probably to add some padding to suit your particular requirements.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
}

 .table > *:nth-child(even)::before {
   content: ":";
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div>key1</div>
<div>value1</div>
<div>key2222222</div>
<div>value2</div>
<div>key3</div>
<div>value3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `div` structure, you can use `display: flex` and could do something like this:

```css
.css-table {
  display: flex;
}

.key {
  width: 10%;
}

.val::before {
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key1</div>
  <div class="val">value1</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key2111</div>
  <div class="val">value2</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key3</div>
  <div class="val">value3</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key4</div>
  <div class="val">value4</div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to specify width, you'll need use JavaScript to calculate the width and apply it inline.

```js
let maxWidth = 0;
  
// Calculate maxWidth
document.querySelectorAll('.css-table').forEach(function(cssTableEl) {
  cssTableEl.querySelectorAll('.key').forEach(function(keyEl) {
    let currWidth = keyEl.clientWidth;

    if (currWidth > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = currWidth;
    }
  });
});


// Apply maxWidth
document.querySelectorAll('.css-table').forEach(function(cssTableEl) {
  cssTableEl.querySelectorAll('.key').forEach(function(keyEl) {
    keyEl.style.width = maxWidth + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
.css-table {
  display: flex;
}

.val::before {
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key1</div>
  <div class="val">value1</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key2111</div>
  <div class="val">value2</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key3</div>
  <div class="val">value3</div>
</div>
<div class="css-table">
  <div class="key">key4</div>
  <div class="val">value4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting a width like 8% does not work on narrow viewports.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You can use javascript to add width inline. You can also use css @media-query and control width on smaller devices.

Comment: Yes you can use JS as you say, but the question did not have a javascript tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the inline-block and make sure the children of the main DIV gets that too and it will automatically resize based on widest width, much like table. No need for flex.

```css
 
.inline-block {
display: inline-block;
}

.inline-block > div {
margin: 2px;
padding: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block">
<div>key1</div>
<div>keykey2</div>
<div>key3</div>
</div>
    
<div class="inline-block">
<div>:</div>
<div>:</div>
<div>:</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-block">
<div>value1</div>
<div>value2</div>
<div>Value3</div>
</div>
```