# Within CSS, is there a way to apply a style such that the maximum child flex column width is used for all siblings?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply a CSS style (at parent and/or child level) to indicate that the child elements are to share the same flex column width? If not, I presume Javascript can accomplish it.

For example, on the below form, I want the three div controls in the first column to have the same width (so that the second columns line up vertically), but I don't want to set a width absolutely or relative to their parent -- rather, I want the **maximum of the flex widths to be used**.

[image: Example form]

**Associated html (for fields only):**

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item-row-label">
            Last Name
        </div>
        <div class="item-row-value">
            <input />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item-row-label">
            First Name
        </div>
        <div class="item-row-value">
            <input />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item-row-label">
            State
        </div>
        <div class="item-row-value">
            <input />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**Associated CSS (for fields only):**

```
.item-row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2.5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-row .item-row-label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-row .item-row-value {
  flex: 1;
}

.item-row .item-row-value input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Use grid not flex and set the column width as max-content. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301413/aligning-key-colon-value-data-in-css-without-using-html-table/71301823#71301823 for en example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to apply a CSS style (at parent and/or child level) to
> indicate that the child elements are to share the same flex column
> width?

For parent level, yes, but you'll have to use `grid` instead of `flexbox`. You can set the property `grid-template-columns` to set the size and number of columns. See the snippet below:

```css
.item-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .2fr 1fr;
  padding: 2.5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-row .item-row-label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-row .item-row-value input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="item-row">
    <div class="item-row-label">
      Last Name
    </div>
    <div class="item-row-value">
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <div class="item-row-label">
      First Name
    </div>
    <div class="item-row-value">
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <div class="item-row-label">
      State
    </div>
    <div class="item-row-value">
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on `grid` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

But if that seem to not fit this requirement:

> but I don't want to set a width absolutely or relative to their parent
> -- rather, I want the maximum of the flex widths to be used.

Then you might want to restructure your html like so:

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.item-row {
  display: grid;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.item-row .item-row-label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-row-value {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="item-row">
    <label for="lastName" class="item-row-label">
      Last Name
    </label>
    <label for="firstName" class="item-row-label">
      First Name
    </label>
    <label for="state" class="item-row-label">
      State
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
      <input id="lastName" class="item-row-value" />
      <input id="firstName" class="item-row-value" />
      <input id="state" class="item-row-value"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may not work in some cases as it is making an assumption that .2fr will be suitable. Use max-content instead.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial value but then it would be back to his original problem which will be uneven length of inputs. I'm currently working on the edit.

Comment: @AHaworth The parent, `item-row` is the `grid` element not the form. You could copy the snippet and see what I meant.

Comment: I was thinking of restructuring so the whole form is a grid.